# IN operator in WQL

Tags: windows, wmi, wmi-query, wql

I need to write a WMI query where I need to check that some value is equal to one of the values in the list, but I didn't find that WQL supports IN operator like SQL.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Device WHERE __CLASS IN ("Device1", "Device20").
```

What are the ways how to write this query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WMI uses the [`WQL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) language which is only a subset of the SQL language, and doesn't include the `IN` operator.

So you can rewrote tor sentence using the OR operator , like so

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk  Where (DriveType=3) or (DriveType=5)
```

or using the your WQL sentence.

```
SELECT * FROM Device WHERE (__CLASS="Device1") OR (__CLASS="Device20")
```

Comment: But in this case the query might grow very much and will not work?